# LDA dimensional reduction newbies (How can a single data transfer/put as a 2 datapoints in a matrix?)

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

How can I put a dataset as a 2 vector point?

I am reading [LDA simple guide](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_lda.html) where the dataset is below.

[image]

And I need to transform to a 2 vector point as below:
How can a single data transfer/put as a 2 datapoints in a matrix?

References [LDA](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/~oveksler/Courses/CS434a_541a/Lecture8.pdf) where it stated:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with yellowish background uses 2-dimesional data set. This is on purpose. Thanks to this plot with red and blue dots can be drawn.

In general LDA can deal with higher-dimensional data sets. Yours is 4-dimesional. You do not need to convert it to 2 dimensions to run LDA.

Comment: Derylo. Thanks. So, mine is 4 dimensional dataset (4 features) and 3 classes. I can only reduce to 2 features? From 4 features to 2?

Comment: Number of features resulting from LDA is $min(p, K-1)$ where $p$ is number of variables in dataset and $K$ is number of classes. In your case $p=4$ nad $K=3$. So you can get 2 features.

Comment: Derylo, thanks. The yellowish background uses 2-dimensional dataset, is 2 features. What happened if I want to plot my 4 dimesional (4 features) in a plot? Will it be 4D? I cannot imagine how can I use this?

Comment: On yellowish background LDA results with one dimension. This is the straight line with dots on it. I don't know why they plotted it oblique not horizontal. Plot of your original data would be 4D, plot of LDA-transformed data would be 2D.